# Android Studio - gradle sync required to run emulator, but needs to be run manually

Tags: android-studio

First problem is that to run an app I need to run Gradle sync after each start, what seems broken

Second problem is that I need to trigger it manually.

Is it possible to at least trigger it automatically?

Comment: After every start of Android Studio or every start of your app?

Comment: @JakubKalinowski Every start of Android Studio

Comment: Did you try something basic like clearing Android Studio cache? File -> Invalidate Caches

Answer (score 0):

Try File->Invalidate Caches.
If this does not work, please provide the logs for more information.